# How do I crosslink properties in a theorem?

Tags: theorems

I am writing something like this

```
\documentclass[15pt]{book}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{vectorspacethrm} A vector space's elements have
these properties

(i) axiom 1 \label{vectorspacethrm1}
(ii) axiom 2

...etc you get the idea.

\end{theorem}

By theorem property 1 \ref{vectorspacethrm1}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to ref them like \label{vectorspacethrm1}

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{a1} prop 1
\item prop2 
\end{enumerate}
```

Later on

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{b1} prop 1
\item prop2 
\end{enumerate}
```

But both \ref{a1} and \ref{b1} have the same labelling name.

Comment: Use a proper enumerated list, use the enumitem package to configure said list

Comment: Off-topic: `15pt` is not a fontsize option that's recognized and processed by the `book` document class.

Comment: @daleif and then referencing is possible?

Comment: Yes, it might be a good idea to read a good introduction to latex, lists are covered in any good introduction to latex.

Comment: @daleif, but this doesn't seem to work if i have multiple enumerate environments. For example, they are called by their numbers

Comment: Full minimal example please. What do you mean by called by their numbers?

Comment: @daleif, see example

Comment: I do not understand your problem. At the moment, vectorspacethrm1 is not referring to any numbers. Please update your question with exactly what you're trying to do. You are not being clear at all.

Comment: @daleif, no just ignore the vector space stuff for now. That one isn't in the enumerate environment, it is obsolete.

Comment: Then what is it you're asking? Of course the two enumerates will have the same outcome, you configured them the same, but since you're using hyperref any refs to them will hit their respective items.

Comment: I want \ref{a1} and \ref{b1} to output different labelling, they both display "1". Is it possible to change their output labelling (say by [text])?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and its `label` and `ref` formats to change the output of `\ref`. In the example below we define a `thmprop` environment that is basically an `enumerate` labelled with Roman numbers and referenced with the full theorem name in front.

The `enumitem` documentation seems to prefer something like the last approach.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{thmprop}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[thmprop]{label={\normalfont(\roman*)},ref=\thetheorem(\roman*)}

\crefname{thmpropi}{property}{properties}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Spaces}\section{V and H}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:vspace} A vector space's elements have
these properties
\begin{thmprop}
\item \label{thm:vspace:prop1} prop 1
\item prop2 
\end{thmprop}
...etc you get the idea.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:hspace} A hector space's elements have
these properties
\begin{thmprop}
\item \label{thm:hspace:prop1} prop 1
\item prop2 
\end{thmprop}
...etc you get the idea.
\end{theorem}

We have \ref{thm:vspace:prop1} and \ref{thm:hspace:prop1}

We have \cref{thm:vspace:prop1} and \cref{thm:hspace:prop1}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:space} A space's elements have
these properties
\begin{enumerate}[label={\normalfont(\roman*)}]
\item \label{thm:space:prop1} prop 1
\item prop2 
\end{enumerate}
...etc you get the idea.
\end{theorem}
We have property~\ref{thm:space:prop1} of Theorem~\ref{thm:space}.
\end{document}
```

[image]